# How to simulate ARIMA model data in python? using statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.simulate()

Tags: python, data-science, statsmodels, arima

Need to know how to simulate data in python using

```
statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.ARIMA.simulate()
```

Hitting error :

```
TypeError: MLEModel.simulate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

self=? IDK why ?
Process=?
nsimulation=?

Comment: You should post more code, more error messages.  I'm guessing you aren't using the API correctly.  Have a look at this example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473268/sampling-with-python-statsmodels-arima-package.  Don't you have to fit first?

Answer (score 0):

The "self" error is basic coding error
just assign a variable for the ARIMA(class) model and call the simulate function using the class variable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).